# C# - displaying the max, min, and average

Tags: c#

I am new to C#. I have been working on this program and researching but am not getting anywhere. The goal is to have the user enter numbers (how many is up to the user). when they enter a 0, it will stop the program and display the minimum number entered, the maximum number entered, and the average of all numbers entered. I am not getting any errors and I am getting. If someone can please point me in the right direction.

The WriteLines are returning:

Lowest number is 0
Highest number is 0
Average is: 0
Count: 5

Here is my code:

```
int LOWEST =0;
int HIGHEST=0;
const int STOP = 0;
double average = 0;
int input;

int count = 0;
Console.WriteLine("Enter a number. You can end the program at anytime by entering 0");
input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
while (input != STOP)
{
     for (int i=0; input != STOP; i++)
     {
           Console.WriteLine("Enter a number. You can end the program at anytime by entering 0");
           input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
           count++;
           var Out = new int[] { input };
           LOWEST = Out.Min();
           HIGHEST = Out.Max();
           average = Out.Average();

           if ((input > LOWEST) || (input < HIGHEST))
           {
                 LOWEST = Out.Min();

           }
           if (input > HIGHEST)
           {
                 HIGHEST = Out.Max();
           }
      }
}


Console.WriteLine("Lowest number is {0}", LOWEST);
Console.WriteLine("Highest number is {0}", HIGHEST);
Console.WriteLine("Average is {0}", average);
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: You need to track those things outside the loop, it's resetting every time.

Comment: you don't need two loops, but to answer your main question, you reset the value every time.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On each run you are constructing a new array of integers:

```
var Out = new int[] { input };
```

After this line, Out contains one item: the last input. Calling `Min`, `Max` and `Average` on it will return the last value. Which is zero if you ended the program.

instead of creating a new array each time, you want to create a `List<int>` at the beginning of your program and then add each input to it. You can then use the whole list of values to calculate `Min`, `Max` and `Average`.

Eventually you can change your code into something like this:

```
const int STOP = 0;
int input = -1;

List<int> Out = new List<int>();

while (input != STOP)
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number. You can end the program at anytime by entering 0");
    input = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    if (input == STOP) break;

    Out.Add(input);

}


Console.WriteLine("Lowest number is {0}", Out.Min());
Console.WriteLine("Highest number is {0}", Out.Max());
Console.WriteLine("Average is {0}", Out.Average());
Console.WriteLine("Count: {0}", Out.Count);
Console.ReadLine();
```

Comment: solution will work, but it will take additional memory, which is not very good in general case, but for learning task - ok

Answer (score 2):

```
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();
        numbers.Add(10);
        numbers.Add(30);
        numbers.Add(20);
        numbers.Add(0);
        numbers.Max();
        numbers.Min();
        numbers.Average();
```

returns 30, 0 and 15.

Answer (score 1):

Before your loop, you should probably make `Out` an extensible data structure analogous to an array, the `List`.

```
List<int> Out = new List<int>();
```

then each loop, you can

```
Out.Add(input);
```

Since this sounds like an exercise for the reader, you can then traverse your list and compute the average from all data values.

---

Alternately, before the loop, you could declare

```
int n = 0;
int total = 0;
```

and each loop, do

```
n += 1;
total += input;
```

From these, you should be easily able to compute the average.