# How to calculate the "average" value , "highest" value , and "Lowest" value in an array? C#

Tags: c#, arrays, winforms

PART 1: I am to create a program that that reads a file’s contents into an array, and displays the array’s contents in a ListBox control, and calculates and displays the total of the array’s values. - DONE THAT PART

PART 2: Calculate the average, Highest, and Lowest value and display them in a Label control.

I'm new to coding so I couldn't do much, I turn to stack overflow for help

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.IO;

namespace SalesAnalysis
{
public partial class SalesAnalysisApplication : Form
{
    public SalesAnalysisApplication()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void salesAnalysisButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //declaring array
        const int SIZE = 100;
        decimal[] sales = new decimal[SIZE];

        //varible to hold amount stored in array
        int count = 0;



        //declaring streamreader
        StreamReader inputFile;

        //opening the sales file
        inputFile = File.OpenText("Sales.txt");

        try
        {
            //pull contents from file into array while there is still 
             // items to pull and the array isnt full

            while (!inputFile.EndOfStream && count < sales.Length)
            {
                sales[count] = decimal.Parse(inputFile.ReadLine());
                count++;
            }
            //close the file
            inputFile.Close();

            //display contents in listbox
            for (int index = 0; index < count; index++)
            {
                salesListBox.Items.Add(sales[index]);
            }


            //Calculate the sum of all values
            for (int index = 0; index < sales.Length; index++)
            {
                totalSales += sales[index];
            }
            //display total of all values
            salesListBox.Items.Add("Total =" + totalSales);


            //Determine the average sales from the array
            for (int index = 0; index < sales.Length; index++)
            {
                //calculate the average
                averageSales = totalSales / 7;
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }

    private void Clear_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //Clear all fields
        salesListBox.Items.Clear();
        averageResultsLabel.Text = "";
        highestResultsLabel.Text = "";
        lowestResultsLabel.Text = "";
    }

    private void exitButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //close form
        this.Close();
    }
}
```

}

Comment: You simply use the extension methods for *IEnumerbale* that does all these things

Comment: Perhaps, you can't do much, but you can always split your problem into smaller parts. For example, you're asking about three different values: start with one, i.e. average, instead. Second step: you already know how to assign a value to a label, you just need to calculate the average value of the array elements, and this question was already asked here: [how can i return the sum , average of an int array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12949933)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19413087/c-sharp-displaying-the-max-min-and-average

Comment: you have already calculated `totalSales` it`s only 1 line from there to the average. Do you at least know how the mathematical operation is to calculate the average?

Comment: as for the min and max values you could do it in the same loop where you calculate the `totalSales`. Do you have any idea how you could find the smallest number if you would step through a series one by one? I guess this is homework, so you probably also want to learn something, am I right?

Comment: `decimal[] sales = File.ReadLines("Sales.txt").Select(line => decimal.Parse(line)).ToArray();` - you don't have to work with streams

Comment: @MongZhu yeah ik the basic math principles -- average = totalSales / the number of arrays, but I do not know how to implement it.

Comment: @MongZhu i think i figured it out, give my code a check again

Comment: almost there. "average = totalSales / the number of arrays," it should be  "average = totalSales / the number of **items** in the array"! you get the amount of numbers by `sales.Length` as you have already used in your for loop

Comment: why do you compare always the number of the position `2` ? in `if (sales[2] > lowestsales)` you need to use your index variable to be able to run through the array: `if (sales[index] > lowestsales)` as well as in the assignment: `lowestsales = sales[index];`

Comment: @MongZhu for some reason the formula "average= totalsales/ sales.lenght" doesnt produce the correct solution - there are 7 items in the array total sum of the 7 items = 10960.07. but using the  "average= totalsales/ sales.lenght" gives a result of 109.60

AND the subscript 2 is the lowest value in the array hence why I am using it to get "lowestSales". if i run:

if (sales[index] > lowestsales)
lowestsales = sales[index] ---- gives me a result of 0 for lowestSales

Comment: Why do you make an array with 100 positions if you put only 7 items in there? The rest of the array will be initialized with the default value of 0.this is why the minimum is 0. Maybe you should use a `List<decimal>` instead of an array

Comment: @MongZhu because its possible that the nnumber of items in the array increases - but that is not within the scope of this program - but i still gave it 100 for the peace of mind. Thanks for all your help!

Comment: You should use a List, it is made exactly for this kind of cases where your collection can increase. It will only contain as much elements as you put into it

Comment: I just saw that you have `int count` to count the amount of stored items. So then you should use this variable as final condition in all your for loops. run with `i < count` and the rest should work just fine. even the line: `if (sales[index] > lowestsales) lowestsales = sales[index]`

Comment: @MongZhu Thanks man, good a good mark, thanks to you!

Answer (score 6):

You can use linq to do this for example:

```
    var list=Enumerable.Range(0,1000);

    var average = list.Average();

    var highest = list.Max()

    var smallest= list.Min()

    var total= list.Sum()
```

P.S do not forget to add `using System.Linq;`

Answer (score 1):

The non-linq approach.

You have a `sales.Length` and a `totalSales`.  Therefore, you have an `averageSales`.

For max & min, while you are in the `for` loop

```
for (int index = 0; index < sales.Length; index ++ 
  {
    if (sales
  }
```

simply assign the value based on an `if` statement.  Something like:

```
if (sales[index] > highestSales) 
{
  highestSales = sales[index];
}
if (sales[index] < lowestSales)
{
  lowestSales = sales[index];
}
```

Comment: I am attempting your non-linq solution, still having trouble. any way I can send u the program?

Comment: @MozzJonas see if the edit helps.  Have you worked out averageSales?

Comment: @MozzJonas I asked you those questions in my comments for a reason. I wanted to help you to develop the algorithm on your own. Would you care to answer them?

Comment: @MozzJonas imagine you have 10 people standing in a row. You walk from the first until the last. How would you find the talest person? You would check the first if he is taller then `0` if so, then you would remember that person, then go to the next one and compare whether he is taller then the one from your memory. If so you would overwrite your memory with the new person and so on

Answer (score 0):

First convert u r `Decimal` array to List.

```
List<decimal> lst = sales.OfType<decimal>().ToList(); // Convert to List.
```

Then Follow `Linq` Operations.

```
lst.Average(); lst.Min();
```

Comment: 1) why using `OfType` ? a simple `sales.ToList()` would do the same 2) where is the need to transform the array into a list? An `decimal [ ]` implements `IEnumerable` and this interface defines the methods `Average` and `Min`. So the array can call these methods on it's own

Comment: The OfType is redundant as all elements are known to be decimal, and the ToList is unnecessary as Min/Max/Avg are defined on IEnumerable which an array already implements.

Answer (score 0):

In case you prefer good old *loop* (and no *Linq*), you can try `File.ReadLines` and `foreach`:

```
  decimal max = 0;
  decimal min = 0;
  decimal sum = 0;
  int count = 0;      

  foreach(string line in File.ReadLines("Sales.txt")) {
    decimal value = decimal.Parse(line);

    salesListBox.Items.Add(value);

    if (count == 0 || value > max)
      max = value;

    if (count == 0 || value < min)
      min = value;

    sum += value;
    count += 1;   
  } 

  decimal average = sum / count; 

  averageResultsLabel.Text = average.ToString("f2");
  highestResultsLabel.Text = max.ToString();
  lowestResultsLabel.Text = min.ToString();
```

Here we don't have to create any array at all. If you insist on having array a simple *Linq* can help

```
  decimal[] sales = File
    .ReadLines("Sales.txt")
    .Select(line => decimal.Parse(line))
    .ToArray();
```

And `foreach` will be

```
  foreach(decimal value in sales) {
    salesListBox.Items.Add(value);
    ... 
  }
```

Comment: yes very nice and simple. But unfortunately I need to use arrays to achieve full marks.